# Magento 2 : Pre fill Textarea Value

Tags: magento2, forms, adminform, ui-form

I added a text area in the admin form and want to show pre-defined text in that. So is it possible and How?

```
$fieldset->addField(
                'approval_note',
                'textarea',
                [
                'name' => 'approval_note',
                'label' => __('Thank you Note'),
                'title' => __('Thank you Note')
                ]
            );
```

I want to show text with the below data by default.

[image]

Need Help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'approval_note',
    'textarea',
    [
    'name' => 'approval_note',
    'label' => __('Thank you Note'),
    'title' => __('Thank you Note'),
    'value' => 'Hello Symon,&#10;How are you?&#10;Thanks for contacting me.'
    ]
);
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Is it display anything or sets any value?

Comment: No.. Its not working

Answer (score 0):

**For Custom Form**

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'approval_note',
    'textarea',
    [
    'name' => 'approval_note',
    'label' => __('Thank you Note'),
    'title' => __('Thank you Note'),
    'values' => 'Default Value'
    ]
);
```

**For System Config**

You can give a default value to the Textarea field by creating a config.xml file.
Place your file in the below-mentioned path

> **namespace\modulename\etc\config.xml**

and add code as below and change "**Section Name**" and "**Group Name**" according to your **system.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <sectionname>
            <groupname>
                <description>Textarea default text</description>
            </groupname>
        </sectionname>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: The text area is not in the system -> configuration section.. It's in my custom form.

Comment: @Krupali sorry for the misunderstanding I'll change my answer.

Comment: @Krupali can you check my answer now

Comment: Define 'values' is not working.

Comment: Try replace values with -   'values' => 'Default Value'    with 'value' => 'Default Value'

Answer (score 0):

If simple "Value" not working then you can add renderer as below.

add below code in your form block e.g main.php

```
 $fieldset->addType(
            'htmldata',
            '\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Renderer\Autofill'
  );
    
   $fieldset->addField(
            'approval_note',
            'htmldata',
            ['name' => 'approval_note', 'label' => __('Thank you Note'), 'title' => __('Product Cost Notes'), 'required' => false,'nl2br' => true,
                'escape' => true]
        );
```

add new file Autofill.php as per definded path in file "Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Renderer" and add below code

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Renderer;
 
/**
* CustomFormField Customformfield field renderer
*/
class Autofill extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    /**
    * Get the after element html.
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        // here you can write your code.
        if($this->getValue()){
            $enquiryData = nl2br($this->getValue());
        }else{
        /*default value
            $enquiryData = "Your default text here";
        }
        return $enquiryData;
    }
}
```

**accept as a solution and do upvote if its works for you.**